# How Can I Add Two Items From Hashtable Into Other Hashtable?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
htOutputDetails = CType(lsListHashtables.Item(0), Hashtable)
```

I want to do something like this...

```
htOutputDetails = CType(lsListHashtables.Item(0, 1), Hashtable)
```

I want to add both items from the other Hashtable, into another Hashtable...but the (0, 1) thing won't work.

Comment: You're looking for some magic solution that neither exists nor makes sense. If you want to add two items from one `Hashtable` to another, first create another `Hashtable`, then get the first item from the first `Hashtable` and add it to the second `Hashtable`, then do the same for the other item. You could potentially use a LINQ query to simplify it but it still amounts to the same thing and you'd still have to create the other `Hashtable` first.

Comment: One has to wonder why you're using a `Hashtable` at all though, given that it was essentially replace with the `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` over a decade ago. Not only that, LINQ includes a `ToDictionary` method, so you could even create the new collection as part of the LINQ query to get the items.